# Supply task parameters using a dictionary variable (Ansible)

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to supply all task parameters using a dictionary in Ansible. Earlier, the `args` module (now [deprecated](https://groups.google.com/g/ansible-project/c/rcBQ4r7pQo8)) was a handy way of doing this. Some tasks that I'm trying to put in a loop have fewer parameters than the rest, and since I don't want any variables to be exposed in my plays, I'm looking for a solution that closely matches the `args` approach.

The dictionary variable (note: the last element doesn't have an 'opts' key/parameter):

```
lvm_vars:
    - {vg: {{ lvm_names.data_vol_group }} , lv: {{ lvm_names.index_lv }} , size: 5G, opts: -i 3 -I 256}
    - {vg: {{ lvm_names.data_vol_group }} , lv: {{ lvm_names.data_lv }} , size: 5G, opts: -i 3 -I 256}
    - {vg: {{ lvm_names.data_vol_group }} , lv: {{ lvm_names.wal_lv }} , size: 5G, opts: -i 3 -I 256}
    - {vg: {{ lvm_names.data_vol_group }} , lv: {{ lvm_names.tblspc_lv }} , size: 5G, opts: -i 3 -I 256}
    - {vg: {{ lvm_names.backup_vol_group }} , lv: {{ lvm_names.backup_lv }} , size: 5G}
```

The args solution:

```
- name: Create LVs ({{ item.lv }})
  lvol:
  args: "{{ item }}"
  with_items: "{{ lvm_vars }}"
```

What the final unrolled tasks should look like:

```
- name: Create LVs
  lvol:
    vg: {{ lvm_names.data_vol_group }}
    lv: {{ lvm_names.index_lv }}
    size: 5G
    opts: -i 3 -I 256
- name: Create LVs
  lvol:
    vg: {{ lvm_names.data_vol_group }}
    lv: {{ lvm_names.data_lv }}
    size: 5G
    opts: -i 3 -I 256
- name: Create LVs
  lvol:
    vg: {{ lvm_names.data_vol_group }}
    lv: {{ lvm_names.wal_lv }}
    size: 5G
    opts: -i 3 -I 256
- name: Create tblspc LV
  lvol:
    vg: {{ lvm_names.data_vol_group }}
    lv: {{ lvm_names.tblspc_lv }}
    size: 5G
    opts: -i 3 -I 256
- name: Create LVs
  lvol:
    vg: {{ lvm_names.backup_vol_group }}
    lv: {{ lvm_names.backup_lv }}
    size: 5G
```

I'm also okay with supplying only the parameter values from the dictionary, but this is problematic because the last item in my dictionary doesn't use the "opts" parameter. So if I try doing something like this:

```
- name: Create LVs ({{ item.lv }})
  lvol:
    vg: "{{ item.vg }}"
    lv: "{{ item.lv }}"
    size: "{{ item.size }}"
    opts: "{{ item.opts }}"
  with_items: "{{ lvm_vars }}"
```

I obviously get an error because 'item.opts' is undefined for the last item.

Comment: [As pointed by the Ansible Core Engineer in the group you are linking over the usage of 
 `args`](https://groups.google.com/g/ansible-project/c/rcBQ4r7pQo8/m/7jGoen7zBgAJ): *This is, in our opinion, very unsafe - especially when that variable may come from something like a fact. It has not been disabled, but will be removed after 2 major versions.*

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is the `default` filter with the special value [`omit`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#making-variables-optional).

> By default Ansible requires values for all variables in a templated expression. However, you can make specific variables optional. For example, you might want to use a system default for some items and control the value for others. To make a variable optional, set the default value to the special variable `omit`

<sup>*Source: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#making-variables-optional*</sup>

```yaml
- name: Create LVs ({{ item.lv }})
  lvol:
    vg: "{{ item.vg }}"
    lv: "{{ item.lv }}"
    size: "{{ item.size }}"
    opts: "{{ item.opts | default(omit) }}"
  with_items: "{{ lvm_vars }}"
```

With this, if your `item` dictionary does not contains the `opts` key, the whole `opts` key of `lvol` will be removed out of the dictionary, so resulting in your last loop being:

```yaml
- name: Create LVs (lvm_names.backup_lv)
  lvol:
    vg: lvm_names.backup_vol_group
    lv: lvm_names.backup_lv
    size: 5G
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thank you!